# Is there a Freelancer map navigator outside of the game?

Tags: freelancer

I love the game and would love to have a separate map navigator outside of the game to use while I play the game. Let's say we grap some information mentioning some planet/depot etc. and I have no idea where it is.

I want to know the way to navigate there. Is there a desktop program or an online tool to navigate the game planet map?

ps.

In the game there is a way to click a point and select `navigate here`. But before clicking, we need to know where to click! That is when I need the nevigator outside of the game.

In other words, it would be lovely to have the places mentioned in the game, e.g. the planet/location where has the highest price of a loods/products.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few:
http://www.cc.puv.fi/~kan/freelancer/index.html

Is one, I'm going to dive through my archived HDDs to find my fave if I can for you.

Comment: Alexis, Welcome to Arqade! Here on the Stack Exchange network, we like our answers to stand the test of time, so we omit traditional greetings and sign-offs.